# Unwanted extra space around Bootstrap typography

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4, there is unwanted space around the top and bottom of text, even after applying `margin` or `padding` to `0`, or playing around the `line-height`. The extra space is still there. It makes aligning elements with text increasingly harder.

See the red line in the following example taken from Bootstrap official doc:

[image]

Comment: try padding: 0;

Comment: Nope. It's neither padding nor margin

Comment: That's the space for p and g to breathe. And of course the whole text needs to be vertically centered in relation. So there's no extra space.

Answer (score 0):

you most likely will need to use the `!important` flag at the end of css rule.

For example:

```
h1 { padding: 0 !important; }
```

It's not the prettiest and probably not the most efficient method, but it usually gets around the bootstrap css rules.

Answer (score 0):

The extra space is not related to the `h1` heading. It is applied through the css selector `.bd-content>table>tbody>tr>td` .

You can try :

```
.bd-content>table>tbody>tr>td {
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lesser line-height like

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
 line-height:0.6;
}
```

This should work as per your requirement or else change the number 0.6... or so